# jQuery ajax call returns page html

Tags: php, jquery

On index.php I have a button that calls a function on index.js which has an ajax call in it

on index.php

```
<div id="forgot" onClick="forgot();">Forgotten Password?</div>
```

on index.js

```
function forgot(){
'use strict';
var user = $("#input_1").val();
    jQuery.ajax({ 
       type: "POST", 
       url: "ajax/index_login.php",
       data: 'user='+user+'&action=forgot', 
       cache: false,
       success: function(response) {
          alert(response);
         }
    }); 
}
```

the php on index_login.php

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'forgot'){
    $clean['user'] = filter_var($_POST['user'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $sql_data['user'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$clean['user']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '{$sql_data['user']}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    exit('success');
}
```

The correct values are being posted but regardless of what value I place in exit() the response is the complete HTML for index.php

Comment: are you not running this off a webserver and also not as `file:///`?

Comment: I'm running it on a webserver

Comment: ok but how, `http://localhost` or `file:///` or is this hosted? If you're seeing "code", it's not being parsed. And is there an opening `<?php` tag?

Comment: it is hosted on subdomain on a webserver

Comment: yes, there is a <?php tag, the rest of the php on the same page is running fine

Comment: You're getting the HTML for `index.php` not `index_login.php`?

Comment: @Barmar - yes, thats the bonkers thing but I think I've sussed it.  I had an include at the top of index_login.php which was commented out but for some strange reason it was still affecting the page but even stranger wasn't affecting any of the other parts of the page.  I've completely deleted the include and now it works.... weird

Comment: why was this voted down?

Answer (score 1):

You're using jQuery, so you don't need to "hard-code" the `onclick` event as attribute in the `forgot` div. So, in "index.php" use just this:

```
<div id="forgot">Forgotten Password?</div>
```

Why? You'll see in the following codes.

Since you want to use POST request, then you don't need to build a query string like `'user='+user+'&action=forgot'`, but an object. How? You'll see in the following codes.

If you want to receive a response, use `echo "whatever response string";`, not `exit("whatever response string");`. If you want to make sure that php stops executing after echo-ing the response, then use `exit();` after `echo "whatever response string";`.

There are two methods of using ajax as a correct solution to your question: receiving the response as a JSON encoded content or as a HTML content.

**Obs:** About the used ajax functions read the notice at the end of the answer.

### 1) JSON encoded response:

#### index.js:

```
/**
 * On document ready.
 * 
 * @return void
 */
$(document).ready(function () {
    activateForgot();
});

/**
 * Activate click event on button "forgot".
 * 
 * @return void
 */
function activateForgot() {
    $('#forgot').click(function (event) {
        var user = $("#input_1").val();

        var ajax = $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "ajax/index_login.php",
            data: {
                'user': user,
                'action': 'forgot'
            }
        });
        ajax.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(response);
        });
        ajax.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + '<br />' + errorThrown);
        });
        ajax.always(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // Whatever you want to do, independent of received response.
        });

        // Important, because it prevents page refresh when a form is used.
        return false;
    });
}
```

**Nota bene**:

- Notice the use of `dataType: 'json'`.
- Notice the use of the data **object**.
- I didn't tested that `cache` property, but it should make no difference.

#### index_login.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    if ($_POST['action'] == 'forgot') {
        if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
            // ...
            echo json_encode('success');
        } else {
            echo json_encode('Please provide a user!');
        }
        exit();
    } else {
        echo json_encode('Not the proper action provided!');
        exit();
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode('Please provide an action!');
    exit();
}
```

**Nota bene:**

- Notice the use of `json_encode`.
- Always provide validation on NULL values first.
- Always provide return values if some condition is not valid. You really don't want to allow the users to see all kind of unhandled errors, which often contain informations about your web server, file system, etc.
- I didn't tested the use with `exit()`, but it should be no problem.

### 2) HTML response:

#### index.js:

```
/**
 * On document ready.
 * 
 * @return void
 */
$(document).ready(function () {
    activateForgot();
});

/**
 * Activate click event on button "forgot".
 * 
 * @return void
 */
function activateForgot() {
    $('#forgot').click(function (event) {
        var user = $("#input_1").val();

        var ajax = $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: "ajax/index_login.php",
            data: {
                'user': user,
                'action': 'forgot'
            }
        });
        ajax.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(response);
        });
        ajax.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + '<br />' + errorThrown);
        });
        ajax.always(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // Whatever you want to do, independent of received response.
        });

        // Important, because it prevents page refresh when a form is used.
        return false;
    });
}
```

**Nota bene:** Just replaced the `dataType: 'json'` with `dataType: 'html'`.

#### index_login.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    if ($_POST['action'] == 'forgot') {
        if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
            // ...
            echo 'success';
        } else {
            echo 'Please provide a user!';
        }
        exit();
    } else {
        echo 'Not the proper action provided!';
        exit();
    }
} else {
    echo 'Please provide an action!';
    exit();
}
```

**Nota bene:** Just used echo without `json_encode`.

### Notices/General recommendations:

- If `alert(response);` gives you some troubles, use `alert(response.toString())`. If it still doesn't work, fill a results div with the response content like this: `$('#results').html(response);`, etc.
- Always use prepared statements and exception handling in php, especially when you are dealing with the data-access layers.

Here are some answers of interest for you, maybe:

- [Using json/html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44433455/form-button-refreshes-on-click-one-page-website/44685878#44685878)
- [Using PDO with prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44594328/mysql-dynamic-link-to-fetch-the-right-row/44594936#44594936)
- [How to prepare and run queries using mysqli library (especially EDIT 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989248/cant-insert-info-in-a-server-but-i-can-as-localhost/44315798#44315798)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you you for taking the time to do this.  Although it didn't answer the question it was very useful :)